# Excel Conditional Formatting for Date colums

Tags: microsoft-excel, conditional-formatting

I have 2 columns with dates and I want to apply conditional formatting to all values where the date in one column is bigger than the date in the other column.

[image]

So, when the dates in "Actual End Date" are greater than the dates in "Requested End Date" column, highlight them in red.

I tried using formulas, I tried simple "greater than rule" with $B>$A and both didn't work. Also, online info that I found was not helpful.

Any ideas? I am using Excel 2013.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use relative references (no dollar sign), by writing down a rule for the first cell of range (ex. `B2>A2`)

Comment: Thanks for the input, but this doesn't work as well. Formatting of cells is the same on both columns.

Comment: It does work on Excel 2013. Did you modify preceeding rule or you wrote a new one? If you did the 2nd, you need to remove the old rule.

Comment: Sure, I cleared all rules from the entire worksheet and created a new rule. Maybe I am doing something wrong.. I tried creating a new rule - Classic with Formula (there I tried =B>A), I also tried creating a new rule with "Greater than" .. but still nothing.

Comment: You need to select desired range, and write a rule also indicating row number of cells: `=B2>A2`

Comment: Ok, that worked. I was selecting the whole column before. Thanks!